# LCI data format in BW2

Tags: lifecycle, brightway

So I want to import my own LCI database to Brightway2, and my process has 3 valuable products.

I found this example with co-products: https://github.com/massimopizzol/B4B/blob/main/02.2_Simple_LCA_co_products.py

The example shows more or less how it works, but I would like to use allocation for my process and not substitution. Should I just change the type to `"allocation"` instead of putting there `"substitution"`, or is bw2 not supporting allocation? Also, if we have 3 valuable products, the first one is part of the main activity as `type="production"`, and 2 others have `'type="substitution"`? And for the other 2, we create 2 separate activities and they are just kinda one exchange activity, in which their type is `production`, like the example?

Besides just to make sure, if one of the inputs has the `type="technosphere"`, we need to create another activity where we show the process behind it. When it comes to raw products, they have the `type="biosphere"`, and their amounts are negative, in comparison to emissions.

I set other valuable products type as `"substitution"` and for each of them I created a new activity, where their type was equal to `"production"`. Overall it worked, but the obtained LCA score wasn't correct, so I don't know if it wasn't conceptual mistake.

Thank you in advance for all your help and time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Brightway currently does not have a model where you can enter a multifunctional process and get the software to do allocation for you. You will need to do the allocation yourself :) Here [is a notebook I wrote up](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/Allocating%20datasets%20manually.ipynb) that shows a simple allocation procedure.

P.S. In the future please only post to one of the beginners mailing list or SO, otherwise everyone doesn't get notified twice.

Answer (score 1):

Changing "substitution" by "allocation" will not work. If you want to use allocation / partition, I would create the activities with the exchanges already allocated.

The meaning of the "substitution" exchange as well as the sign conventions for biosphere flows is explained in the documentation [here](https://2.docs.brightway.dev/intro.html#exchanges).